# Webpack how to load images referenced in my src/index.html to dist/images/

Tags: webpack

I've been trying to figure this out for a while but I can't seem to find a good answer. How do I automatically load an .svg, .png, or .jpg image that's referenced in the index.html file?

```
<img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo__image">
```

It woks when I reference the image in my scss file like this:

```
.background {
  background: url('./images/logo.svg');
}
```

This is my webpack config rule:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
  loaders: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        attrs: ['img:src', 'source:srcset'],
        name: 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom output and public paths by using outputPath and publicPath

**publicPath**

*webpack.config.js*

```
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    publicPath: 'assets'
  }  
}
```

**outputPath**

*webpack.config.js*

```
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    outputPath: 'images'
  }  
}
```